# How is the Book of Mormon different from the Bible?

Tags: bible, lds, book-of-mormon

What are the differences between the Book of Mormon and the Bible? How are they similar? What do they have in common?

Please provide an overview of the major differences. I prefer a Mormon perspective.

Comment: This is a VERY broad question that could be answered multiple ways, from a high-level overview to an in-depth discussion on differences in doctrinal teachings. I'm not sure this is answerable in a StackExchange format.  Can you clarify your question? Make it more focused so that it's possible to give a reasonable answer?  Already, this is attracting varied answers that could all be "right".  see [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)

Comment: In the mean time, welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Here are some meta posts about this site to help you learn how we do it here: [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379) and [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808) Please also take the [tour] and see the [help]. I hope to see you post again soon. Please also keep in mind that I and other users are willing to help you, so ask us anything if you need help.

Comment: I've edited this into an overview question. Ref: [I'm not clear exactly how "overview" questions work](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3795)

Comment: I also added that you prefer a Mormon perspective, in light of your self answer.

Comment: I think it's still too broad. An overview would need to look at history, literary aspects, theology, and more.

Comment: fredsbend: I'm not clear on how to stamp this question as an overview. Is there some kind of metatag for that, or was I just supposed to use the word "overview" in my question?

Comment: @SweatCoder I made the edit for you, but essentially, the topic needs to be narrow enough (sort of subjective to any who might close vote) and you do need to explicitly ask for an overview. There's currently two close votes for being too broad, but I think it's fine. One a different note, I only saw your message by chance. Type `@username` and that user will be pinged.

Comment: @fredsbend: Got it. Wilco.

Answer (score 3):

To understand the differences between the BOM and the Holy Bible, we first must look at these two volumes of scripture within the context of their similarities. So **here is what they have in common**:

1. They are both volumes of scripture written by prophets.
2. Millions of people study (and believe in) each, though manifestly at least 100X more people accept the Bible than the BOM.
3. They both have similar objectives: persuade people to believe in God and live peaceful/productive lives.
4. In terms of theology and doctrine, most of what is in the Bible and the Book of Mormon is unproveable and must be taken on faith.
5. Both were written over a very large span of time.

**Here are the significant points of difference between the Bible and the Book of Mormon:**

6. The Book of Mormon contains a consistent theme from start to finish: persuading people to believe and follow Jesus Christ. In the Bible, a similar theme exists in the New Testament, but it's often harder to detect in the Old Testament, and our Jewish friends would presumably conclude that there is no such theme in the Old Testament (Torah/Talmud).
7. The Bible has numerous sections that are non-doctrinal in nature, such as historical, proverbial, and legalistic. The Book of Mormon has elements of these as well, but is mostly either doctrinal on the surface, or contains doctrinal undertones.
8. Nearly all Catholics, Protestants, and Evangelicals believe that the Bible is the word of God and the BOM is not. Nearly all Mormons believe that *both* are the word of God.
9. BOM prophetic writers frequently make reference to the Bible, especially to the writings of Isaiah. The Bible makes no direct reference to the Book of Mormon, but Mormons believe there is a veiled reference to BOM peoples in John 10:16..."`And other sheep I have, which are not of this fold: them also I must bring, and they shall hear my voice; and there shall be one fold, and one shepherd.`" Mormons believe that Jesus visited the people on the American continent shortly after His ascension spoken of in the Bible.
10. Nearly everything in the Bible takes place in the Middle East. While the Book of Mormon begins in Jerusalem, describing a family that flees the city into the desert, the vast majority takes place on the ancient American continent (long before the term "America" existed).
11. The Book of Mormon was translated from a single collection of ancient metal plates, and all within a single year. The Bible was pieced together over thousands of years and translated by many different people.

Comment: Your 12th point is comparing apples to oranges. You start by talking about translation of the BoM then say the Bible was pieced together over thousands of years. You are referring to different things. The rest is fine. +1 and welcome to the community.

Comment: Did you get this from a source, by the way, or is this all original?

Comment: Point 6 is incorrect. The Bible is not translated from translations of translations.

Comment: @curiousdannii - Point 6 is not incorrect, not all translations of the Bible were translated from codecies, many modern language translations were made using the KJV as their source. Even those codecies that were used in the more authoritative translations aren't original manuscripts, they're merely the oldest available. Christ didn't preach in Greek, and I don't think Moses spoke the same form of hebrew as the Jews did during the Roman occupation.

Comment: I removed point 6 about translations and renumbered. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @ShemSeger You're right that there are still many translations from the English (and a handful from the Latin). But the overall impression it gives is unhelpful, especially as most people reading this will be reading English translations which are only one step removed from the sources. Translating how Jesus spoke doesn't really count - most Christians consider the Greek NT to be inspired so that's what matters. As for Moses, I think it's likely that the OT was translated over time too, but again the text we have is what's considered inspired.

Comment: Concerning point 9: There are other scriptures in the holy Bible that Mormons view as hints to the Book of Mormon, especially Ez 37:16,17 and Isa 29:11,12,18. However, there might be even more such scripture passages.

Answer (score 3):

The Book of Mormon has a much greater consistency of style than does the Bible, which is much more clearly the work of many authors over a period of centuries. In the Bible, only Mark's Gospel has sentences frequently begin with 'And', whereas sentences frequently begin with 'And' in any book within the Book of Mormon. This consistency seems somewhat unlikely to have resulted from translation, and suggests that the various authors of the Book of Mormon were influenced to adopt the same style as *Mark*.

In the Book of Mormon many sentences start with an extension through to 'And it came to pass ...': opening the pages at random, I see Jacob 5:25: "*And it came to pass that when the Lord of the vineyard ...*" and Alma 50:35: "*And it came to pass that the army which was sent ...*" The Mormon community maintained a surprisingly consistent literary style over many centuries.

The Old Testament never mentions Jesus by name, and passages often interpreted as referring to the Messiah are seen as having other possible interpretations. The Book of Mormon directly mentions Jesus Christ by name more than 500 years before his birth (2 Nephi 20: "*... and as the Lord God liveth, there is none other name given under heaven save it be this **Jesus Christ**, of which I have spoken, whereby man can be saved.*"

The New Testament is somewhat ambiguous as to when Jesus was born. In the Book of Mormon, 3 Nephi 1:19 tells us that the date of Jesus' birth was unmistakable because there was no night that day, right across the world; a footnote tells us the exact year - 1 AD.

The Old Testament was written in Hebrew, with some Aramaic in places, then translated into Greek, while the New Testament was written wholly in Greek. They were translated into Latin and then various styles of English, including the somewhat archaic KJV English (and into other languages used around the world).  The Book of Mormon was first translated in 1830 into the English of the KJV Bible and subsequently translated from English into [other languages around the world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Book_of_Mormon_translations).

The Bible and the Book of Mormon both have similar objectives: persuade people to believe in God and live peaceful/productive lives. In terms of theology and doctrine, most of what is in the Bible and the Book of Mormon is unproveable and must be taken on faith.

Comment: I can't find the quote at the moment, but I recall reading that all those "Ands" are actually a grammatical necessity in the ancient Egyptian language, which the Book of Mormon narrative claims to have used as a basis for their writing due to its great compactness.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Mormon 9:32-33 tells us that the books were written in the Hebrew language, only using Egyptian characters for conciseness. In other words, there is no suggestion that the Egyptian language (syntax, grammar, etc) were involved.

Comment: One of the biggest differences is that there are actually several commonly accepted 'Bible's, though they share a lot of the same books, and the formation process of the Bible and what books different Churches include in it is examinable from a historical standpoint.  There is only one 'version', so to speak, of the BoM (i.e. all BoM contain the same 'books' with the same verses) and the decisions made as to the inclusion or exclusion of the (presumably many) various possible works were theoretically made by God, wheras the Bible was compiled over time through the authority of the Priesthood.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer - `"the inclusion or exclusion of the (presumably many) various possible works were theoretically made by God"` Where do you get that idea from? The canon of the Book of Mormon was arranged by the Prophet Mormon. More than once in the BofM Mormon states: *"I cannot write the hundredth part of the things of my people."* It was Mormon, by the authority of the Priesthood that compiled the Book of Mormon from a library of records. The resulting BofM is a hundredth part of the records in the New World that were available to him.

Comment: @ShemSeger  The point is that the plates of a particular set of prophets was given to Smith to translate.  Smith did not choose from a variety of plates, and there are not any non-golden-plate potentially inspired texts from the time.  As a result, since the tradition of the Mormon church starts in the 1800s from a single source (Smith)-- and since the BoM started with the church rather than being developed by it over time-- it doesn't have the same diversity of content that the Bible does: all BoM have the same books.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer - That's a good thing. It's the diversity of content in the Bible that has created so many schisms in Christianity. There are no disagreements between Churches on the interpretation of scripture in the Book of Mormon by those who embrace it as inspired scripture.

Comment: @ShemSeger Is that comment really helpful in improving this answer?

Comment: @ShemSeger and thedarkwander.  You may have completed your conversation about the diversity of content in the BoM to your mutual satisfaction; if so, good. If not, please continue in a chat room. Comments placed here should be those that might helpful in improving my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Most theology of Book of Mormon is similar to the Bible's.However, these five distinctive theological positions are Mormon's, I gather:

- The Old Testament prophet Isaiah prophecy about voices that would "[whisper out of the dust](http://biblehub.com/isaiah/29-4.htm)," are [believed to refer to the publication of the Book of Mormon](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/isa/29.4?lang=eng).
- Adam and Eve ( Hava) eating from the forbidden tree, otherwise known as The Fall, is necessary for humans to experience sexuality, and humans' knowlege and redemption: "[Adam fell that men might be, and men are, that they might have joy.](https://www.lds.org/manual/gospel-principles/chapter-6-the-fall-of-adam-and-eve?lang=eng)"
- The church should be named the [Church of Jesus Christ](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/gs/church-name-of?lang=eng#).
- [The atonement of Christ](https://www.lds.org/ensign/1988/12/unique-insights-on-christ-from-the-book-of-mormon?lang=eng) saves unbaptized people including children who die without baptism.
- The death and resurrection of Jesus brings " a universal resurrection for all mankind, regardless of a person’s belief or performance", all people ("[both old and young, both bond and free, both male and female, both the wicked and the righteous](http://josephsmithpapers.org/paperSummary/book-of-mormon-1830?p=260)") will be resurrected with an immortal physical body .

Though I am not a Mormon, I ( now this is a subjective statement, not part of the answer) find Mormon position on children and non-Christians is generous compared to orthodox Christianity's. It is more closer to people general perception of God's justice and mercy.